# Why are the blank options not being set for ng-options within a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-options

I'm trying to create an AngularJS Directive to manage the promps of a `<select>` input. The 3 different modes are as follows:

1. Don't allow a blank option

   - This is the default behavior
2. Allow a blank option with no text

   - Achieved by setting `allow-blank="true"` on the directive
3. Allow a blank option with prompt text

   - Achieved by setting `allow-blank` to any value other than `"true"`

However, **the blank options are never available.**

## [Demo on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/C9Glo7rNH7HbYKHovDA3?p=preview)

### Template

```
<select ng-options="tag.id as tag.name for tag in myTags">
  <option ng-if="allowBlank === 'true'" value=""></option>
  <option ng-if="allowBlank && allowBlank !== 'true'" value="">{{allowBlank}}</option>
</select>
```

### Directive

```
myApp.directive('mySelector', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    templateUrl:'my-selector-template.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      allowBlank: '@?'
    },
    replace: true,
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.myTags = [
        {"name":"aliquam in","id":1},
        {"name":"massa velit","id":2},
        {"name":"nec vestibulum","id":3}
      ];
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Since `my-selector` uses `replace` and the `ng-options` inside your template binds `tag.id` as the `select` model, the values in your controller will be used to select from the values available in your `$scope.myTags` array (i.e. always "aliquam in" as it has an `id` of one). Having multiple value semantics (i.e. as a boolean, as a string) for your `allow-blank` attribute feels a little strange to me.

Comment: I opened a ticket with AngularJS - [#8408](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8408)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the content of the `select` is <strike>transcluded</strike> (see below). If you inspect the elements that are output you don't even see the option tags you defined inside.

As you're just using a string you should use a pre-linking function where you add the correct option in via javascript. The following code should do the trick (Forked [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/34ZhdEHA6oNQWkwd9Zys?p=preview)).

```
link: {
  pre: function(scope, element, attrs){
    if(attrs.allowBlank === 'true') element.append('<option value=""></option>');
    else if(attrs.allowBlank && attrs.allowBlank !== '') element.append('<option value="">' + attrs.allowBlank + '</option>');
  }
}
```

**EDIT** The select does not 'transclude' it's contents, as @lightswitch05 pointed out the select directive grabs the first child with `value=""` as the empty node ([source ref](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/11f5aeeee952a395edaf54e3277674f211a82fc7/src/ng/directive/select.js#L236)). Then later it clears out the contents of the select and dynamically adds in the relevant `<option>` tags ([source ref](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/11f5aeeee952a395edaf54e3277674f211a82fc7/src/ng/directive/select.js#L354))

Comment: But my directive isn't transcluded

Comment: The problem is that `ng-options` is initialized before `ng-if` is evaluated. Causing only the first option to ever get read. [see the angular source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/11f5aeeee952a395edaf54e3277674f211a82fc7/src/ng/directive/select.js#L236)

Comment: Ah yes, you're right it isn't transclusion on the select directive, I'll updated my reasoning to be correct.